# ViewModel returns ArrayList size as zero

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-paging

I am using Android `Paging` library to load data from server in my `RecyclerView`. I am able to see the data properly but when i print the size of the list, it returns me zero.

Following is my code:

```
val itemViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this, MyViewModelFacotry(disciplineId, schoolId, yearId)).get(StudentInfoViewModel::class.java)
        activity?.let {
            itemViewModel.itemPagedList.observe(it, Observer<PagedList<StudentData>> { studentDataPagedList ->
                if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                    Log.i("MainActivity",studentDataPagedList?.size.toString())
                }
                studentInfoNameAdapter?.submitList(studentDataPagedList)
            })

            recyclerView.adapter = studentInfoNameAdapter
        }
```

The `Log` statement prints always zero. I want to show a `TextView` if list is empty but the list always returns size as zero.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the `PagedList` for the first time it could be empty if `setEnablePlaceholders(false)` was provided as configuration. If you want or can handle `null` values, you might enable placeholders. If there's just no data yet, you might want to look into different approaches.

You could wrap you adapter with a custom implementation which delegates the dataset changes properly and displays a single item when the original adapter has no items.

The [PagedList documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList) states in regard of the placeholder:

> **Placeholders**
>
> There are two ways that PagedList can represent its not-yet-loaded
>   data - with or without `null` placeholders.
>
> With placeholders, the PagedList is always the full size of the data
>   set. `get(N)` returns the `N`th item in the data set, or `null` if its
>   not yet loaded.
>
> Without `null` placeholders, the PagedList is the sublist of data that
>   has already been loaded. The size of the PagedList is the number of
>   currently loaded items, and `get(N)` returns the `N`th loaded item.
>   This is not necessarily the `N`th item in the data set.

Comment: But the problem is that the log statement is only printed once with value 0 and I am also seeing the data in the RecyclerView.

Comment: It is only printed once, because you only receive the list once. The list itself will be populated later.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution. I am kind of stuck here for more than 2 days.

Comment: It might be out of scope a bit. Have a look at [this blog post](http://alexzh.com/tutorials/how-to-setemptyview-to-recyclerview/) or try to look for something similar with google. There might be libraries for it already.

Comment: Thanks, the link helped.

Answer (score 0):

> The Log statement prints always zero. I want to show a TextView if
>   list is empty but the list always returns size as zero.

If list is empty, its size should be zero so it's correct behaviour.

If you're getting empty list all the time than the problem is somewhere else, propably in the place when you extract data and add it to the list.

Comment: I am getting the list and also the data is displayed. But the size of studentDataPagedList is always zero.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to show the empty state using `RecyclerView.AdapterObserver` as shown below:

**Initialize and register the AdapterObserver**

```
        val adapterDataObserver = object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
            showEmptyState(myAdapter.itemCount == 0)
        }

        override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
            showEmptyState(myAdapter.itemCount == 0)
        }
    }
       myAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(adapterDataObserver)
```

Also, don't forget to unRegister the AdapterObserver in `onDestroy()`